# Correct arcthitectural term for a Database of Web Service

Tags: database, web, service, architecture

Databases and Web Services have similar but slightly different roles, but imagining them to be black boxes with an access layer over the the top; what single word could you use to refer to either?

Datasource or repository don't work because they just refer to databases.
I need an actual term and not just something made up. Something that is actually googleable and real.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In what context are you talking about?  btw...  If you want to google it, google searches do support phrases and other lengthy descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Server" ?  That usually describes the whole system, including any resources available, along with services and we just always assume there's a database in there, as well.